# How do I add a spacer between columns in Vuetify without hurting the grid?

Tags: css, vuetify.js

I have a simple grid layout that is meant to be responsive: the header is always full-width, the photo and its metadata take half-screen columns but are switched to full-width on mobile devices:

```
<v-layout row wrap>
  <v-flex xs12>
    <div class="text-h4">Some header</div>
  </v-flex>

  <v-flex md6 xs12>
    <img src="../assets/placeholder_350x150.png" alt="">
  </v-flex>

  <v-flex md6 xs12>
    ..more stuff..
  </v-flex>
</v-layout>

...

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

I'm trying to add space of fixed width between the columns and make them fill the rest as before (half/half or full/full, depending on device). How do I do that in Vuetify?

Here's what I've tried:

1. added

   ```
   <v-spacer></v-spacer>
   ```

   between the columns. That haven't affected the result at all. Well, that's not surprising as those seems to only be [designed](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids/#spacers) for filling space that (column) components don't took themselves
2. added margins to the column components. That produced width overflow and I got the 2 columns in 2 "rows", not in 1.
3. added (symmetrical) paddings to the column components. That kinda worked, but in that case I have to add such paddings to other parts of the grid too (like the header above), otherwise they get offset on the left and on the right (the former is noticible because of the header)

Things I haven't really tried:

4. asymmetrical paddings? come on, I'll have to make them responsive (otherwise they will hurt mobile layout) if I use them, and the whole approach is just ugly
5. CSS grid? Well, I'll have to make it responsive too but may be that's the only ok available option..

Is there some beautiful way to achieve this using Vuetify's grid system?
(5. sounds like I have to re-build grid myself)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, while writing the question I've come up with a somewhat ok answer: along with the `v-spacer`, I added a `md6_narrower` class to the column components and added

```
@media all and (min-width: 960px) {
  .flex.md6_narrower {
    max-width: calc(50% - 1em);
  }
}
```

styles. This is an ok solution, but it relies on Vuetify implementation (the `.flex` selector to overwrite styles from `.flex.md6`, the 960px ↔ md breakpoint), so it is limitedly reliable.

Please share, if anyone has a more reliable solution, I'll re-accept the answer.